# Full Google Chrome removal

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, deb, purge, software-uninstall

I installed Google Chrome from a `.deb` file, but for security reasons later removed it, but that appears not to have removed all of it (me purging it through apt, maybe this is because the file did not match the packaging guidelines), so I have searched my system for `google-chrome`, and `google-chrome-stable`. And I found a folder in the `.cache` area, and then another folder which was to do with configuration (I think). Anyway, so I removed those, but now there still remain here `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` these two files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 176 Apr 25 21:29 google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 207 Apr 25 22:53 google-chrome.list.save
```

I have disabled the Google Chrome repository and removed it in my System Settings GUI, so what are these files, and can I just delete them? Also, are there any other changes installing Google Chrome would have made that I need to undo or delete (please note that I am not fully sure if my Google Chrome package had been tampered with during the download or not and no longer have the `.deb` file, so I am wondering if there is also a log that would tell me all the changes that particular installation made)?

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.save` file was created by APT from the original `.list` file that Chrome added. It's intended as a backup and doesn't actually affect anything. The `.distUpgrade` file was *probably* created by APT when you when you did a release upgrade (I'm assuming you did). The Chrome package is unaware of them (Chrome didn't have anything to do with their creation), so purging that package leaves these files alone.

> Can I just delete them?

Yep.

> [A]re there any other changes installing Google Chrome would have made that I need to undo or delete[?]

Without the original package, we can't say for sure.

> I am wondering if there is also a log that would tell me all the changes that particular installation made[.]

Nope. Unless you use a HIDS or similar system which keeps track of files in your system, the apt log only states what happened from an overall state (X was removed, Y was installed, etc.).